# Using atomic variable to storage cv::Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5, raspberry-pi4, stdatomic

I'm working in a application that's use opencv to capture frames and show it's in a window. The code use's the frame to record a video too, but, when I show the frame and record at the same time, the frame rate in screen decreases. Can I use a atomic variable to store the frames? like that:

```
std::atomic<cv::Mat> atomicFrame;
atomicFrame.store(newFrame);
cv::Mat sameFrame = atomicFrame.load();
```

My idea is uses the atomic variable to access the same frame at the same time in `show_frame_on_screen` function and `record_frames` function, but, when i set the variable in my header file, my cpp program get some errors.

A part of my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher_record_frame;
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher_show_frame;
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher_get_frame;
    QProcess *processKeypad;
    QTimer *savingTimer;
    QTimer *framesRecordTimer;

    cv::VideoWriter *videoWriter;

    std::queue<cv::Mat> framesQueue;
    std::atomic<cv::Mat> frameAtomic;
};
```

A part of my .cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

In line `ui->setupUi(this);` i get the error when passing the `this` parameter:

```
mainwindow.cpp:10:17: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QMainWindow *' with an rvalue of type 'MainWindow *'
ui_mainwindow.h:40:31: note: passing argument to parameter 'MainWindow' here
```

If I comment the line `std::atomic<cv::Mat> frameAtomic;` or change to `std::atomic<int> frameAtomic;` the error in cpp file disappear.

This application is running in a RaspBerry Pi 4 8gb, with raspbian OS.

EDIT:
At this moment, my code have this functions to refresh the frames, show then and record then.

```
void MainWindow::update_frame()
{
    while (fvs.more())
    {
        cv::Mat frame = fvs.read();
        if (recording)
        {
            framesQueue.push(frame);
        }
        emit show_frame_on_screen(frame);
    }
}

void MainWindow::show_frame_on_screen(cv::Mat frame)
{
    cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(1024, 600));
    QImage image(frame.data, frame.cols,
                 frame.rows, frame.step,
                 QImage::Format_BGR888);
    ui->layer_frame->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
void MainWindow::thread_record_frame()
{
    while (!framesQueue.empty()){
        cv::Mat newFrame = framesQueue.front();
        framesQueue.pop();
        newFrame = write_text_on_frame(newFrame);
        videoWriter->write(newFrame);
        if (!recording && framesQueue.empty()){
            savingTimer->stop();
            ui->layer_loading->setText("");
            videoWriter->release();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `std::queue<cv::Mat> framesQueue;` to storage all frames and record then.

Comment: What size is `cv::Mat`?  If it's larger than 16 bytes, it won't be lock-free so each access will take and release a spinlock around copying the object.  If it is just the size of one or two pointers, then yeah it perhaps could be viable, but you still have to manage deallocation after being sure the last reader is done looking at it.

Comment: It's a matrix (1920x1080), so, about your explanation, my tries does not make anything better, I will try another path to increase the performance of recording and work well with concurrence in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::atomic<cv::Mat> atomicFrame;` makes little sense.
`cv::Mat` is an n-dimensional array, and making it atomic isn't feasible.

Atomics are only meant for very small objects.
For anything large, reading or writing the atomic object wouldn't be lock-free and might be no better than guarding all access with a `std:mutex`.
Also, you're most likely interested in accessing small parts of the `atomicFrame`, not just replacing it in its entirety. `std::atomic` does not give you that option.

Instead, you should double-buffer, which means that you use two separate buffers to `show_frame_on_screen` and `record_frames`.
This allows you to simultaneously draw and record on separate threads without contention.
When a frame is done drawing, you swap the buffers.

`std::atomic<cv::Mat>` is not useful for this; you could instead use a pair of `cv::Mat*`, guarded by a `std::atomic<bool>`.

```cpp
std::array<cv::Mat, 2> buffers;
cv::Mat* screen_buffer = &buffers[0];
cv::Mat* record_buffer = &buffers[1];
std::atomic<bool> request_frame = false;

void show_frame_on_screen() {
    // if an old request for a frame is still active, block until it isn't
    request_frame.wait(true);
    do_show(screen_buffer);
    request_frame.store(true);
    request_frame.notify_one();
}
```

There are two approaches to implementing `record_frames`:

```cpp
// low-energy variant: only record a frame when needed
void record_frames() {
    request_frame.wait(false);
    do_record(record_buffer);
    std::swap(screen_buffer, record_buffer);
    request_frame.store(false);
    request_frame.notify_one();
}

// low-latency variant: never wait for the frame to be shown on screen, always draw
//                      (this variant is wait-free)
void record_frames() {
    do_record(record_buffer);
    if (request_frame.load()) {
        std::swap(screen_buffer, record_buffer);
        request_frame.store(false);
        request_frame.notify_one();
    }
}
```

As for the error caused by `ui->setupUi(this);`, it's unclear why this happens, without seeing your full code, or a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added a edit in my post, showing more about my code. Now, I'm using a queue to access the frames, and i want to try another path's, because I produce more frames than I'm can consume in `thread_record_frame`, this make me to wait a very long time to end the record, to not lose some frames. I thought that using an atomic variable could increase performance for recording frames. I'll try your suggestion and come back later.

Comment: @JorgeAugustoWilchen I've added another version which only produces as many frames as are consumed. In principle, you can get away without a queue but only two buffers. You still wouldn't lose any frames this way.

Comment: Looking [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), can i affirm do you using c++ 20, wright? In my project, I'm using  c++ 11, in this version, the `std::atomic<bool>` does not have a member called `wait`, do you have any other suggestion for my case? I had tagged the post that I'm using c++ 11, but the post was edited.

Comment: @JorgeAugustoWilchen yeah, the `wait` and `notify` mechanism for atomics is a C++20 novelty. You can do the same with a `std::mutex`, one or two `std::condition_variable`s, and a `bool` in C++11. See [std::atomic<bool>::wait vs. std::condition_variable::wait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77826765/5740428)