# std::atomic<bool>::wait vs. std::condition_variable::wait

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, condition-variable, stdatomic

I have a single producer, single consumer use case where the consumer blocks until the producer has made new data available.
Here are two synchronization approaches that implement this:

#### New C++20 approach using `std:atomic<bool>::wait`

```cpp
data d;
std::atomic<bool> ready = false;

void consume_bool() {
    ready.wait(false);
    do_consume(d);
    ready.store(false);
    ready.notify_one();
}

void produce_bool() {
    ready.wait(true);
    d = do_produce();
    ready.store(true);
    ready.notify_one();
}
```

#### Traditional C++17 approach using `std::condition_variable`

```cpp
data d;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable consume_ready, produce_ready;
bool ready = false;

void consume_cv() {
    std::unique_lock lock{m};
    consume_ready.wait(m, [] { return ready; });
    do_consume(m);
    ready.store(false);
    produce_ready.notify_one();
}

void produce_cv() {
    std::unique_lock lock{m};
    produce_ready.wait(m, [] { return !ready; });
    d = do_produce();
    ready.store(true);
    consume_ready.notify_one();
}
```

#### Question

To me, it seems like the C++20 approach has entirely obsoleted the old approach.
Is there a reason to still use traditional `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` synchronization?

Also, is waiting with `std::atomic_bool` as efficient (i.e. no busy-wait) as waiting for a `std::condition_variable`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859596/difference-between-stdatomic-and-stdcondition-variable-wait-notify-method) help?

Comment: @JakobStark yeah, it explains the difference in principle, but it's still unclear to me whether one approach really obsoletes the other.

Comment: It seems to me that "single producer, single consumer use case" is a rather well-defined situation, where there aren't really any options to consider. If it works, it works, and you don't need the old approach. But at the end of your question, it looks like you are asking in general, and not just in your use-case. Clarify?

Comment: @anatolyg if waiting through `std::atomic_bool::wait` is somehow inferior to waiting on `std::condition_variable`, then that'd be a reason to use the old version, at least in some cases. It's a general question, but the point is to float ideas of what could be used to justify the old version in this particular example.

Comment: Old approach does not require any atomics because condition is protected by mutex lock. And it is still handy if condition is more complex than just a boolean flag.

Comment: @user7860670: Conversely, the lock-free atomics version doesn't require a mutex at all, except as a way to get OS-assisted sleep/wake if you don't have C++20.  Hopefully code that already wanted to use atomics can just use `.wait` on one of their atomic vars without missing out on anything.  And code that wanted to use a mutex anyway can keep using condition variables and / or just blocking when they try to take the mutex.

Comment: I *think* under the hood on Linux both basically end up making a `futex` system call, but condition vars have always seemed over-complicated to me, which I assume is because I don't really understand the use-case in non-lock-free code.  IDK what the complexity gives you that you don't get with something simple like `.wait` for an atomic to have a different value than it does now, perhaps nothing useful for lock-free code.  So I'd like to see an answer from someone who understands the point of condition variables as well as how they're implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question really is: Why where `wait` calls on atomics introduced?

I found some potential hints about that in [p0514r4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0514r4.pdf):

> we also propose simpler atomic free functions that enable
> incremental change to pre-existing algorithms expressed in terms of atomics, to benefit from the
> same efficient support behind semaphores

So this seems about 'fixing' the atomic API by adding a 'missing' synchronization feature. Another proposal ([p0995r1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0995r1.html)) for adding wait to `atomic_flag` reads along the same lines:

> Our experience is that atomic_flag's interface is so minimal as to be mostly useless [...]
>
> We’ve heard of it being used as:
>
> - A questionable spinloop (as was originally intended);
> - A "check-in" flag used to know when at least one thread has reached a program location.

Because users are (mis)using atomic flags for synchronizing threads, the API is enhanced to give them obvious better choices than spinning on the atomic.

From experience it also seems to me that people just understand atomics really fast compared to the mutex + condition_variable + lock + semaphore + latch + barrier mess that the C++ standard library provides. Therefore enhancing that simple API with some useful functionality makes some sense to me.

---

With that in mind I would answer your question as follows:

The new atomic wait/notify API is just another synchronization API in C++. I would assume that implementators choosing the most efficient implementation will use the same underlying synchronization method in both cases.

That beeing said, one big reason to use the `std::mutex`/`std::condition_variable` API could be, that it supports waits with timeout (`wait_for`/`wait_until`), whereas the atomic API does not.